# DNS of 0.0.0.0?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, dns, ethernet

I have one main router in the house and a wireless range extender (edimax ew-7209apg).

My main router uses the default ISP DNS servers provided.

Many devices could connect to the wireless range extender without any problems (e.g. my phone or kindle). However I ran in to problems today with my Raspberry Pi where it kept getting assigned a DNS of 0.0.0.0 from DHCP so it was connected to the LAN but couldn't get any connection to the internet at large.

However I went in to my range extender's settings and noticed it had a DNS setting of 0.0.0.0. So I changed it from that to 8.8.8.8 and now the raspberry pi works. Except the raspberry pi is now listing its primary DNS as the same IP address as the default gateway (my main router) - 192.168.2.1. So:

1. Why could some devices connect without trouble while the Pi couldn't? How were the DNS settings of the working devices configured if the extender was using 0.0.0.0?
2. Why is my Pi's new DNS not 8.8.8.8? Instead it's my default gateway?

Comment: "Why is my Pi's new DNS not 8.8.8.8? Instead, it's my default gateway?" - Because you configured the system to use the DNS of the router instead of specifically configuring the DNS, which is normal, one less device to worry about if you ever change it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question - No real way of knowing that unless you revert the situation to what it was so we can check the differences between the devices that work and those that don't. My best guess would be that some devices default to using a public DNS service (e.g., 8.8.8.8) if they don't receive a DNS server address from the DHCP server, or maybe they just had a DNS server configured manually.

Regarding your second question - Your router acts as a DNS forwarder, i.e., it's a DNS server that receives queries from your local network and forwards them to a public DNS server, possibly also caching responses for faster lookups of frequently visited addresses. The setting that you have changed is the address of the DNS server that the router forwards those queries to. This is done on the router itself. For the actual computers on your network, the router is the DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers 